# NSContactPicker not displaying picker window in SwiftUI on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, contacts

I have tried to get the NSContactPicker to display a picker window in SwiftUI on macOS.  Here is my code. If you click on the button nothing happens. What am I missing?

```
import SwiftUI
import Contacts
import ContactsUI

let d = MyContactPicker()

class MyContactPicker: NSObject, CNContactPickerDelegate
{
    var contactName: String = "No user selected"
    
    func pickContact()
    {
        let contactPicker = CNContactPicker()
        contactPicker.delegate = self
    }
        
    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPicker, didSelect contact: CNContact)
    {
        contactName = contact.givenName
    }
}

struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var contact: CNContact?
    var picker = MyContactPicker()
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Text(picker.contactName)
            Button("Select Contact")
            {
                picker.pickContact()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `CNContactPicker` uses `showRelative(to:of:preferredEdge:)` to present it

Comment: How do you get the NSView parameter from SwiftUI?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible starting point using `NSViewRepresentable` and an `NSView` subclass

```
class NSContactPickerView: NSView, CNContactPickerDelegate {
    
    let didSelectContact: (CNContact) -> Void
    
    init(didSelectContact: @escaping (CNContact) -> Void) {
        self.didSelectContact = didSelectContact
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        Task {
            showPicker()
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func showPicker() {
        let picker = CNContactPicker()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.showRelative(to: .zero, of: self, preferredEdge: .maxY)
    }
    
    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPicker, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
        didSelectContact(contact)
    }
}


struct ContactPicker: NSViewRepresentable {

    let didSelectContact: (CNContact) -> Void
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSContactPickerView {
        NSContactPickerView(didSelectContact: didSelectContact)
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSContactPickerView, context: Context) {
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var contact: CNContact?
    @State private var showPicker = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(contact?.givenName ?? "")
            Button("Select Contact") {
                showPicker = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showPicker) {
            ContactPicker { contact in
                self.contact = contact
            }
            .frame(width: 1, height: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but it's not very elegant. Maybe someone else can improve on this.

Comment: This displays the picker beautifully but doesn't let you select the contact. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried a few things out but no luck, I'm afraid